# An Azure Application Insights dashboard similar to DataDog/New Relic?

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights

Having used New Relic and more recently DataDog at previous work places, I'm now trying to get my head around Azure's Application Insights.

Is there any way to view all your logs within Application Insights in a similar dashboard to the screenshot below i.e. view all your logs in a datetime order and be able to filter by custom values e.g. service name, log level etc.?

[image: this]

Answer (score 1):

Azure Application Insights provides a rich set of tools for monitoring, analyzing, and visualizing log data, although the UI may be different but features are very similar to platforms like New Relic and DataDog.

You can view and filter logs in Application Insights:

1. **Log Analytics**:

   - Navigate to your Application Insights resource in the Azure portal.
   - Click on "Logs" in the Monitoring section. This will open the Log Analytics workspace.
   - Here, you can write Kusto Query Language (KQL) queries to filter and analyze your logs.

[image: Log Querying]

2. **View Logs in Chronological Order**:

   - In the Log Analytics workspace, you can use the following query to view traces (logs) in chronological order:

     ```
     traces
     | order by timestamp desc
     ```
3. **Filter by Custom Values**:

   - You can filter logs using the `where` clause in KQL. For example, to filter logs by a specific log level:

     ```
     traces
     | where customDimensions.LogLevel == "Error"
     | order by timestamp desc
     ```
   - Similarly, to filter by service name:

     ```
     traces
     | where customDimensions.ServiceName == "MyService"
     | order by timestamp desc
     ```
4. **Visualizing Logs**:

   - You can create charts, graphs, and other visual representations directly from the Log Analytics workspace.
   - Once you have the data you need, click on the "Chart" icon above the results pane and choose the type of visualization you want.
5. **Pin to Dashboard**:

   - If you want a persistent view of your logs or visualizations, you can pin them to an Azure dashboard. This way, you can have a custom dashboard with all the logs and metrics that matter to you.
6. **Search**:

   - This is one of my most favourite ones, Search or transaction search. The "Search" feature in Application Insights provides a user-friendly way to search across telemetry events, including custom events, traces, exceptions, and more.
     [image: Transaction Search]

Comment: Hmm, I don't have the Search option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Application Insights provides a feature called Log Analytics that allows you to query and view your logs in a flexible manner. Here's how you can achieve a view similar to what you described:

Accessing Log Analytics:

Navigate to your Application Insights resource in the Azure portal.
Under the "Monitoring" section, click on "Logs".
Querying Your Logs:

Application Insights uses a query language called Kusto Query Language (KQL). You can use KQL to filter, sort, and analyze your logs.
For example, to view all your traces in datetime order:

```
traces
| order by timestamp desc
To filter by custom values like service name or log level:
```

```
traces
| where customDimensions["ServiceName"] == "YourServiceName"
| where severityLevel == "Information"
| order by timestamp desc
```

Customizing Your View:

You can pin query results to a shared dashboard or export them for further analysis.
Application Insights also provides a feature called "Workbooks" which allows you to create custom interactive reports and visualizations based on your logs.
Additional Filters:

On the top of the Log Analytics page, there are filters available for Time Range, and you can also set custom time ranges.
You can also use the "Schema" pane on the left to explore the different tables and columns available in your logs.